# OpenID connect AzureAD redirect_uri is null

Tags: .net, azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, httpd.conf

I have an .net .6 linux application behind an httpd reverse proxy.

When redirected to azure for authentication, I get the following error

AADSTS90102: 'redirect_uri' value must be a valid absolute URI.

And the URL above is

https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=YYY&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F%28null%29%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=zzz&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=6.17.0.0

I think the big takeaway here is redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F%28null%29%2Fsignin-oidc

I have all the following in my Program.cs

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseForwardedHeaders();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseSession();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

And my appsettings.json is

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mydomain.com",
    "TenantId": "xxx",
    "ClientId": "yyy",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
}
```

My Enterprise application has the following URL

https://somesite-dev.mydomain.com/signin-oidc

And my httpd configuration has

```
 ServerName somesite-dev.mydomain.com

  ProxyRequests Off
  RequestHeader set Host %{HOST}s
  RequestHeader set X-Real-IP %{REMOTE_ADDR}s
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-For %{REMOTE_ADDR}s
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Host %{SERVER_NAME}s
  ProxyPass / http://1.2.3.4:8888/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://1.2.3.4:8888/
```

xxx,yyy,zzz, somesite-dev, and mydomain.com are changed for security reasons.

With all that, why is my redirect URI null? This works fine from the VS debugger

I have removed additional entries from the Enterprise Application, to contain only
ServerName somesite-dev.mydomain.com

[Azure AD Callback][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cr7x.png

**Update 1**

It is no longer null, but I get this instead

AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'https://1.2.3.4:8888/signin-oidc' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application 'yyy'. Make sure the redirect URI sent in the request matches one added to your application in the Azure portal. Navigate to https://aka.ms/redirectUriMismatchError to learn more about how to fix this.

The IP matches the server behind the reverse proxy

```
  ProxyRequests Off
  RequestHeader set Host somesite-dev.mydomain.com
  RequestHeader set X-Real-IP %{REMOTE_ADDR}s
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-For %{REMOTE_ADDR}s
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Host %{SERVER_NAME}s
  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
  ProxyPass / http://1.2.3.4:8888/
  ProxyPassReverse / https://somesite-dev.mydomain.com/
```

**Update 2**

I've had to add this line to my Program.cs and now it works.

```
uilder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
        {
            context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://somesite-dev.mydomain.com/signin-oidc";
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you please share the screencap of the your RedirectURI which you have set?

Comment: @Harshitha Where would I find that?

Comment: In the AppRegistration => Authentication

Answer (score 0):

You must use HTTPS for the redirect URI because otherwise cookies (due to the samesite attribute) will be blocked, and everything will break.

Perhaps remove as this is typically set as the default anyway.

```
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
```

r make the URL in there absolute, like:

```
"CallbackPath": "https://somesite-dev.mydomain.com/signin-oidc"
```

Comment: I would appear that callback path must start with a /

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
ArgumentException: The path in 'value' must start with '/'. (Parameter 'value')
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString..ctor(string value)

Remove the line completely also gives the null redirect error

Comment: The redirect URI should be the full complete URL , not the relative path and it must match exactly the one registered in AzureAD. This is the URL that AzureAD will use to redirect the call back to your application.